# How to save key value pair of array from JSON in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, json, array

Here is my test code trying to save data what I am getting in request, but it is not saving in table.

```
$json = '{  
   "isMobileConfirm":false,
   "cid":"85036",
   "managerid":"12345",
   "location":"12.961125000000001,77.64933166666667",
   "studentprofilepic":"studentprofilepic_1496989696628",
   "studentfrontpic":"studentfrontpic_1496989698785",
   "studentbackpic":"studentbackpic_1496989703275",
   "govtfrontpic":"govtfrontpic_1496989713175",
   "govtbackpic":"govtbackpic_1496989707848",
   "selfiepic":"selfiepic_1496989713394",
   "extrapic":[  
      {  
         "extra_imagepath":"extrapic_1496989714945",
         "extra_doctype":"Hostel Bill\/Receipt",
         "extra_docremark":"gvvg"
      }
   ],
   "loanpic":[  
      "LFA\/loanpic_1496989716375"
   ]
}';


  $student = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load(85036);
        // load cmupload
        $cmuploads = Mage::getModel("manager/cmuploads");
        // decode the json data into arrya
        $obj = json_decode($json,true);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($obj);
        // check is array or not
        if(is_array($obj)){
            foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
                echo $key;
                echo $value;
                                // if not array save data student pics
                if(!is_array($value)){
                    $cmuploads->setCustomerId(85036);
                    $cmuploads->setFileName('studentprofilepic_1496989696628');
                    $cmuploads->setFileFilekey('studentprofilepic');
                    $cmuploads->setManagerId($value->managerid);
                    $cmuploads->setStatus(1);
                    $cmuploads->setLocation($value->location);
                    $cmuploads->setCreatedDate(NOW());                               
                } else if(is_array($value)) {
                    // If it's array check its loan pic or extra pics

                }
            }
            try {
            $cmuploads->save();
         }
         catch(exception $ex2){
            echo "sa";
         }
        }else {
```

Comment: Can you please share the error while saving?

Comment: No error is coming it is saving , but only hardcoded one not others

Comment: what  to pass  $cmuploads->setManagerId($value->managerid); instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below

```
$json = '{  
   "isMobileConfirm":false,
   "cid":"85036",
   "managerid":"12345",
   "location":"12.961125000000001,77.64933166666667",
   "studentprofilepic":"studentprofilepic_1496989696628",
   "studentfrontpic":"studentfrontpic_1496989698785",
   "studentbackpic":"studentbackpic_1496989703275",
   "govtfrontpic":"govtfrontpic_1496989713175",
   "govtbackpic":"govtbackpic_1496989707848",
   "selfiepic":"selfiepic_1496989713394",
   "extrapic":[  
      {  
         "extra_imagepath":"extrapic_1496989714945",
         "extra_doctype":"Hostel Bill\/Receipt",
         "extra_docremark":"gvvg"
      }
   ],
   "loanpic":[  
      "LFA\/loanpic_1496989716375"
   ]
}';

 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
  $student = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($obj['cid']);
        // load cmupload
        $cmuploads = Mage::getModel("manager/cmuploads");
        // decode the json data into arrya


        // check is array or not
        if(is_array($obj)){

                    $cmuploads->setCustomerId($obj['cid']);


                    $cmuploads->setManagerId($obj['managerid']);

                    $cmuploads->setCreatedDate(NOW());                               

            }
            try {
            $cmuploads->save();
         }
         catch(exception $ex2){
            echo "sa";
         }
        }else {
```

Comment: but i need to save all parameters

Comment: I have given 2-3 field as an example.Please do the same for other fields.